# Haskell: How to improve performance of deep recursion and random number generation

Tags: performance, haskell, recursion, random

The problem of interest is to enhance the following Haskell program with a recursion depth of 100,000,000 by making it faster:

```
s :: Int32 -> Int32 -> IO Int32
s 0 acc = return $! acc
s n acc = do r <- randomRIO (0, maxBound :: Int32)
             s (n-1) $! (acc + r)

main = do z <- s 100000000 0
          putStrLn $ show z
```

This program takes about 70 seconds on my machine.
However, a corresponding C program takes only one second:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>    

int main(){
    double startTime;
    double timeEllapsed;
    unsigned int sum;
    long long i;    

    startTime = clock();
    srand(time(NULL));    

    sum = 0;
    i = 0;
    for(i=0; i<100000000;i++){
      sum += rand();
    }    

    timeEllapsed = (clock() - startTime) / (CLOCKS_PER_SEC);    

    printf("sum = %u, time ellapsed = %lfs\n", sum, timeEllapsed);    

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;    
}
```

Where does this difference come from? Is the implementation of random numbers in the Haskell standard library slower? Or should you use a function different from randomRIO? Or has it to do with lazy evaluation?
Can you optimize anything on the Haskell program and make it faster?

It's clear that there might be performance differences between a very high level language like Haskell and C, but I did not expect it to be in the order of ~70 times slower, so I wonder about the causes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the [`random`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/random) library is very slow. `randomRIO` isn't ideal in this situation but using other functions `random` won't help much with the speed. There are several alternatives, Bryan O'Sullivan [`mwc-random`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mwc-random) is the most popular but there's also Don Stewart's [`mersenne-random`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mersenne-random) and my own [`pcg-random`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pcg-random). Also note that C's `rand` isn't a particularly good random number generator.

Here's a similar `mwc-random` version of your code that runs in 2.3s on my machine (ghc-7.10.2, with `-O2 -fllvm`)

```
import Control.Monad.ST
import qualified System.Random.MWC as MWC
import Data.Int

s :: Int32 -> Int32 -> Int32
s n s = runST $ do
  g <- MWC.create

  let go 0  !a = pure a
      go !i !a = do
        w <- MWC.uniformR (0, maxBound::Int32) g
        go (i-1) (a + w)

  go n s

main :: IO ()
main = print $ s' 100000000 0
```

The equivalent code using `System.Random.PCG` runs in 1s for me. And on the experimental fast pure pcg code it can run in 0.28s:

```
import System.Random.PCG.Fast.Pure

s :: Int32
s = go (100000000::Word64) 0xcafef00dd15ea5e5 0
  where
  go 0   _ a = a
  go !i !s a = go (i-1) s' (a + fromIntegral r)
    where P s' r = bounded 2147483647 s

main = print s
```

So Haskell's certainly capable of fast random number generation.